# Range Breaks not working for financial years and week crossover - plotly

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a graph in plotly with the xaxis (int64) which is the yearweek. So the 52nd week in FY22 would be 2252 and the 1st week in FY23 2301.

This has been ok, plotting wise until I have come to a crossover of years. Visually 2252, 2301 and 2302 should all have a difference of one unit however 2252 to 2301 visually looks like 49 units and then 2301 to 2302 is one unit.

I have put in and used rangebreaks but visually nothing is changing.

[I want that big long line to be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4atj.png)

I have the following code and added in rangebreaks but to no avail.

`def sales_line_chart_weekly(location):

```
sales_line_weekly_chart_df = sales_line_chart_df.groupby(['YearWeek','Location Name'])['Sales ex VAT'].sum()
sales_line_weekly_chart_df = sales_line_weekly_chart_df.reset_index()

traces = []
for location in sales_line_weekly_chart_df['Location Name'].unique():
    sales_line_chart_by_location = sales_line_weekly_chart_df[(sales_line_weekly_chart_df['Location Name']== location)]
    traces.append(go.Scatter(
        x = sales_line_chart_by_location['YearWeek'],
        y = sales_line_chart_by_location['Sales ex VAT'],
        name=location,
        ))
return {'data': traces,
        'layout': go.Layout(title='Sales by Location by Week',
                           xaxis={'title': 'Date', 
                                  'type': 'linear',
                                  'rangebreaks': [{'bounds': [2253, 2300]}]},
                           yaxis={'title': 'Sales ex VAT', 'tickformat': '.1f'})
                           }`
```

Comment: Range breaks are only valid for time series data. In this case, a string of year and week numbers would be enough to draw a continuous series.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't want the periods, weeks, quarters to be dates so I created a new column that ranked from 1. This will reset everytime new data is added.

I used this as the tickval and the ticktext was `YearWeek`.

```
def sales_line_chart_weekly(location):    
    
    sales_line_weekly_chart_df = sales_line_chart_df.groupby(['WeekDatesRanked','Location Name', 'YearWeek'])['Sales ex VAT'].sum()
    sales_line_weekly_chart_df = sales_line_weekly_chart_df.reset_index()
    
    traces = []
    for location in sales_line_weekly_chart_df['Location Name'].unique():
        sales_line_chart_by_location = sales_line_weekly_chart_df[(sales_line_weekly_chart_df['Location Name']== location)]
        traces.append(go.Scatter(
            x = sales_line_chart_by_location['WeekDatesRanked'],
            y = sales_line_chart_by_location['Sales ex VAT'],
            name=location,
            ))
    return {'data': traces,
            'layout': go.Layout(title='Sales by Location by Week',
                               xaxis={'title': 'Date',
                                      'tickvals': sales_line_chart_by_location['WeekDatesRanked'].astype(str),
                                      'ticktext': sales_line_chart_by_location['YearWeek']
                                      },
                               yaxis={'title': 'Sales ex VAT', 'tickformat': '.1f'})
                               }
```